# How to use setExtendedAccessToken()

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using Graph api to create a facebook  app with PHP .

```
require_once("facebook.php");
  $config = array();
  $config[‘appId’] = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
  $config[‘secret’] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // NEVER USED THIS , JUST INCLUDED IT !
  $config[‘fileUpload’] = true; // optional
  $facebook = new Facebook($config);


$app_id = "xxxxxxxxx";
    $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $my_url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token']; // The acess call :)

       $at = $params['access_token']; // I USE THIS ACCESS TOKEN
```

I now use that access token ($at) to make requests . But i need to store the access_token for much longer time (60 days) .

So 
1)how do i use setExtendedAccessToken() method & 
2) where i should put that in my code &
3) where can i obtain the output from

***I am including the PHP SDK too ,  even though i am not using it .***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exachange temporary Token for Extended Token. check below code.

```
try {
        $graph_url   =  "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?";
        $graph_url  .=  "client_id=".$FB_APP_ID;
        $graph_url  .=  "&client_secret=".$FB_APP_SECRET;
        $graph_url  .=  "&grant_type=fb_exchange_token";
        $graph_url  .=  "&fb_exchange_token=".$fb_temp_access_token;

        $response   = @file_get_contents($graph_url);            
        $params     = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);

        $new_token  =$params['access_token'];

    } catch (Exception $e) {
       //DO NOTHING
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend an `access_token`, read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Put it at the end, after you have already have an acces_token from the login.

You get the output in the same manner you would with other API calls.

Answer (score 0):

The code I am using to get access token is:

`$access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();`

I just put this code like this.

```
if($userid){

       try{

         $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
         echo $access_token;
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e){
       //catch error here
}
else{

$loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>'your_url','scope'=>'publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages');
exit("<script>window.top.location.replace('$loginUrl');</script>");
}
```

It does store access token that will expire about 2 month ( I use [this tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check).